# Array of objects, extract highest values

Tags: php, arrays, object

Given an array of objects stored in `$my_array`, I'd like to extract the 2 objects with the highest `count` value and place them in a separate object array. The array is structured as below.

How would I go about doing that?

```
array(1) { 
     [0]=> object(stdClass)#268 (3) { 
             ["term_id"]=> string(3) "486" 
             ["name"]=> string(4) "2012" 
             ["count"]=> string(2) "40"
     } 
     [1]=> object(stdClass)#271 (3) { 
             ["term_id"]=> string(3) "488" 
             ["name"]=> string(8) "One more"
             ["count"]=> string(2) "20"  
     } 
     [2]=> object(stdClass)#275 (3) { 
             ["term_id"]=> string(3) "512" 
             ["name"]=> string(8) "Two more"
             ["count"]=> string(2) "50"  
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this many ways.  One rather naive way would be to use [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the array, and then pop off the last two elements:

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a->count == $b->count) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $a->count < $b->count ? -1 : 1
});

$highest = array_slice($arr, -2, 2);
```

**Edit:**

Note that the previous code uses an anonymous function, which is only available in PHP 5.3+.  If you're using < 5.3, you can just use a normal function:

```
function myObjSort($a, $b) {
    if ($a->count == $b->count) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $a->count < $b->count ? -1 : 1
}

usort($arr, 'myObjSort');

$highest = array_slice($arr, -2, 2);
```

Comment: Worth a comment that the anonymous function will only work in PHP 5.3+

Comment: @sberry:  Thanks, I'll make note of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) then write a function that checks the value of count.